# How to display loading option in microsoft bot emulator in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, botframework

When I send message in **microsoft bot emulator**, whether it is possible to bring the **loading options until the response comes to the bot** in node.js. So that I can understand that my program is running in background.

Is this possible in **nodejs**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the ShowTypingMiddleware class from the botbuilder module